# Where do log files go when using the slf4j in cq5?

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, slf4j, aem

I am new to slf4j and have a few questions. Where do log files go when using the slf4j.Logger in cq5

I am currently using eclipse to build the jar files.Can anyone please tell where can I see log file.

I could not see that log information in crx-quickstart/log path.

Do I need to configure anything in pom.xml to specify log file location?

Answer (score 3):

In CQ5 log ouput is written to /crx-quickstart/logs/error.log by default.

Additional loggers can be easily created in the Configuration tab of your CQ5 web console 
/system/console/configMgr by adding an additional "Apache Sling Logging Logger Configuration".
Each logger allows to to define the logger specific log level, message pattern and a log file path relative to /crx-quickstart. The default is always logs/error.log.

Answer (score 0):

Slf4j is just an abstraction layer on top of another logging framework (it doesn't actually do any logging or have configuration).  In the case of CQ the underlying logging framework is log4j.

The log4j configuration file for CQ is located here:

```
crx-quickstart/server/runtime/0/_crx/WEB-INF/log4j.xml
```

Look in that configuration file to see where the logs are currently being written.  I believe that the CQ log locations can also be modified via JMX console.

Answer (score 0):

See also the CQ logging docs at http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configure_logging.html and the Apache Sling docs at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/logging.html (as that's what powers CQ).